# Bidirectional Many to One Mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, mapping

I am new to JAVA and JPA, I googled for solution but no avail. I found a lot of examples but they didnt worked in my scenario.
I want to map these two tables given below:

**Bookshelf Table**

```
CREATE TABLE "SOA2"."BOOKSHELF"  (  
"BOOKSHELF_ID" NUMBER(19,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"NAME_TXT" VARCHAR2(255 CHAR), 
 PRIMARY KEY ("BOOKSHELF_ID") USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 
 MAXTRANS 255 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
 TABLESPACE "SOA2"  ENABLE
 ) SEGMENT CREATION DEFERRED PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 
 MAXTRANS 255 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING TABLESPACE "SOA2" ;
```

and

**Book Table**

```
CREATE TABLE "SOA2"."BOOK" (    
"BOOK_IX" NUMBER(19,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"BOOKSHELF_ID" NUMBER(19,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"NAME_TXT" VARCHAR2(255 CHAR), 
 PRIMARY KEY ("BOOK_IX", "BOOKSHELF_ID") USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 
 MAXTRANS 255 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING   TABLESPACE "SOA2"  ENABLE, CONSTRAINT "FK_RJWHY4FC" 
 FOREIGN KEY ("BOOKSHELF_ID")
 REFERENCES "SOA2"."BOOKSHELF" ("BOOKSHELF_ID") ENABLE) 
 SEGMENT CREATION DEFERRED PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 
  MAXTRANS 255 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING  TABLESPACE "SOA2" ;
```

for easy understanding their structure is shown below

[Bookshelf Table](http://postimg.org/image/w911awsot/)
 and 
[Book Table](http://postimg.org/image/yrrbpc3st/)
After all searches I used Eclipse "JPA Entities from Tables" tool.
It generated following classes for me:

**Bookshelf.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="BOOKSHELF")
public class Bookshelf implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name="BOOKSHELF_ID", unique=true)
    private long bookshelfId;
    @Column(name="NAME_TXT")
    private String nameTxt;
    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Book
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="bookshelf", cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    private List<Book> books;
    public List<Book> getBooks() {
        return this.books;
    }
    public void setBooks(List<Book> books) {
        this.books = books;
    }
//Code removed for the sake of brevity
}
```

**Book.java**

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="BOOK")
    public class Book implements Serializable {
        @EmbeddedId
        private BookPK id;
        @Column(name="NAME_TXT", length=255)
        private String nameTxt;
        //bi-directional many-to-one association to Bookshelf
        @ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
        @JoinColumn(name="BOOKSHELF_ID", nullable=false, insertable=false, updatable=false)
        private Bookshelf bookshelf;
    //Code removed for the sake of brevity
    }
```

**BookPK.java**

```
@Embeddable
public class BookPK implements Serializable {
@Column(name="BOOK_IX")
private long bookIx;
@Column(name="BOOKSHELF_ID", insertable=false, updatable=false, unique=true, nullable=false)
private long bookshelfId;
public BookPK(long bkShlfId, long bkId) {
    this.bookshelfId = bkShlfId;
    this.bookIx = bkId;
}
//Code removed for the sake of brevity
```

}

I am testing this as: **Test.java**

```
        //Physics Bookshelf
        Bookshelf physicsShelf = new Bookshelf();
        physicsShelf.setNameTxt("Physics");
        physicsShelf.setBookshelfId(500);
        //Add Books
        Book book1 = new Book();
        book1.setNameTxt("God and the Physics");
        book1.setId(new BookPK(500, 600));

        Book book2 = new Book();
        book2.setNameTxt("Hyperspace");
        //if I pass 500 as first param in below constructor 
        //Changing 500 to 501 solves the issue
        book2.setId(new BookPK(500, 600)); //javax.persistence.EntityExistsException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [books.Book#books.BookPK@8a6d]

        //Add Books into list
        List<Book> bookList = new ArrayList<Book>();
        bookList.add(book1);
        //Error: Following error appears if I uncomment the following line
        bookList.add(book2); //Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-02291: integrity constraint (SOA2.FK_RJ) violated - parent key not found
        //Set Books
        physicsShelf.setBooks(bookList);
        EntityTransaction transaction = entitymanager.getTransaction();
        transaction.begin();
        entitymanager.persist(physicsShelf);
        transaction.commit();
```

*physicsShelf* inserts only one book successfully, If I insert second book in *bookList* it gives me error described in **Test.java** comments.

Please guide me

1. what I am doing wrong and how to correct it. I am really stuck.
2. Is there any way to to get rid of **BookPK.java** class by annotating other two classes.

**I can not change the database**
**I am using oracle 11g with JPA 2.1**

Any help would be highly appreciated

Regards

Comment: Should the bookId for book2 be different than bookId for book1? In the above code, both seem to have the same id as 600 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The id should be unique but in your case you are setting the both the id of book1 and book2 to Book(500,600)

```
book2.setId(new BookPK(500, 600)); //javax.persistence.EntityExistsException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [books.Book#books.BookPK@8a6d
```

So when you try adding a `book2.setId(newBookPK(500,600));` it is complaining that it already exists.

try

```
book2.setId(new BookPK(500, 601));
```

Edit: for 2nd question

I think you can. In your Book entity try replacing

```
@EmbeddedId
private BookPK id;
```

with

```
@Id
@Column(name="BOOK_IX")
private long bookIx;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I thought I have tried it. It worked. Sorry for the stupid question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What about my second question?